# ¿Modificar un programa en c++?

Tags: c++

Les dejo este bloque de código el cual quisiera modificar la función de `quitar_nodo`: La cual elimina un nodo buscado, pero previamente el usuario lo ingresa por pantalla.

La modificación seria eliminar el menor valor de la lista, pero ya no se tendría que ingresar por pantalla:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
//definicion de estructuras
typedef struct tnodo *pnodo;
typedef struct tnodo{
                int dato;
                pnodo ant;
                pnodo sig;
        };
typedef struct tlista{
                pnodo inicio;
                pnodo fin;
            };          
 //prototipos de funciones y procedimientos
 void menu(int &op);
 void iniciar(tlista &lis);
 void crear_nodo(pnodo &nuevo);
 void agregar_final(tlista &lis, pnodo nuevo);
 pnodo quitar_nodo(tlista &lis, int valor);
 void mostrar(tlista lis);
 void liberar(tlista &lis);  
 main()
 {//variables
    tlista lista;
    pnodo aux,nuevo;
    int numero, op;
    iniciar(lista);
    do
       {
                system("cls");
                menu(op);
                switch(op){
                case 1: cout<<"agregar elemento"<<endl;
                
                crear_nodo(nuevo);
                agregar_final(lista,nuevo);                     
                break;
        case 2: cout<<"Quitar un elemento"<<endl;
                cout<<"ingrese valor a quitar: "<<endl; 
                cin>>numero;
                    aux=quitar_nodo(lista, numero);
                    if(aux!=NULL)
                        cout<<"elemento eliminado:"<<aux->dato<<endl;
                    else
                        cout<<"el valor no existe"<<endl;   
                break;
        case 3: cout<<"elementos de la lista"<<endl;
                //if(lista_vacia(lista)==false)
                    mostrar(lista);
        
                break;
        case 4: cout<<"Fin del programa"<<endl;
                //liberar(lista);
        default:    cout<<"opcion incorrecta"<<endl;                                                            
    }
    system("pause"); 
}while(op!=4);
system("pause");
}
//procedimientos y funciones
 void menu(int &op)
 {
cout<<"*********MENU***********"<<endl;
cout<<"1-agregar un elemento"<<endl;
cout<<"2-quitar un elemento"<<endl;
cout<<"3-mostrar elementos de la lista"<<endl;
cout<<"4-salir del programa"<<endl;
cout<<"elegir opcion"<<endl;
cin>>op;
}


void iniciar(tlista &lis)
{
lis.inicio=NULL;
lis.fin=NULL;
}
void crear_nodo(pnodo &nuevo)
{
nuevo=new tnodo;
if(nuevo!=NULL)
{
    cout<<"ingrese valor";
    cin>>nuevo->dato;
    nuevo->sig=NULL;
    nuevo->ant=NULL;
}
}
void agregar_final(tlista &lis, pnodo nuevo)
{
    if(lis.inicio==NULL)
{
    lis.inicio=nuevo;
    lis.fin=nuevo;
    
}
else
{
    nuevo->ant=lis.fin;
    lis.fin->sig=nuevo;
    lis.fin=nuevo;      
}
lis.inicio->ant=lis.fin;
lis.fin->sig=lis.inicio;
}
pnodo quitar_nodo(tlista &lis, int valor)              //funcion quitar_nodo
{
pnodo p, aux;
if(lis.inicio==NULL)
    aux=NULL;
else
    if(lis.inicio==lis.fin) //unico elemento
        {if(lis.inicio->dato==valor)    //si es el elemento?
        {
            aux=lis.inicio;
            lis.inicio=NULL;
            lis.fin=NULL;
        }
        else
            aux=NULL;
        }
    else        //varios elementos
    {
        if(lis.inicio->dato==valor)
        {
            aux=lis.inicio;
            lis.inicio=aux->sig;
            lis.inicio->ant=lis.fin;
            lis.fin->sig=lis.inicio;
            aux->sig=NULL;
            aux->ant=NULL;
        }
        else
            if(lis.fin->dato==valor)
            {
                aux=lis.fin;
                lis.fin=aux->ant;
                lis.inicio->ant=lis.fin;
                lis.fin->sig=lis.inicio;
                aux->sig=NULL;
                aux->ant=NULL;
                
            }   
            else    
            {
                for(p=lis.inicio->sig;p!=lis.fin && p->dato!=valor;p=p->sig);
                if(p==lis.fin)
                    aux=NULL;
                else
                    {aux=p;
                        (p->ant)->sig=p->sig=aux->sig;
                        (p->sig)->ant=aux->ant;
                        aux->sig=NULL;
                        aux->ant=NULL;
                    }
                    
                    
            }
    }
    return aux;
 }
void mostrar(tlista lis)
{
pnodo p;
if(lis.inicio==NULL)
    cout<<"lista vacia"<<endl;
else
    {for(p=lis.inicio;p!=lis.fin;p=p->sig)
        cout<<p->dato<<endl;
    cout<<p->dato<<endl;}       
}
void liberar(tlista &lis);
```

Podría considerar esta siguiente función que es la de buscar el menor dato y desde ahí mezclarlo con la función `quitar_nodo`, una vez encontrado el menor valor.

```
void mayor_dato(tlista lis)
{
    pnodo menor, p;
    if(lis.inicio != NULL)
    {
        menor=lis.inicio;
        for(p=lis.inicio->sig;p!=lis.fin;p=p->sig)
            if(p->dato<menor->dato)
                menor=p;
        //mostrar(menor->dato);                     //here
            
    }
    
        cout<<"no hay registros"<<endl;
 }
```

El primer código anda a la perfección, el tema es modificar la función `quitar_nodo`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que intentaste???

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?